# Is there a function $f$ or $g$ that makes this true?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}$  $f(x)$ DNE , and $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}$ $[f(x) + g(x)] = 42$

Comment: I don't think so, given that every proof of the additivity of limits rule I have seen requires that the limits exist

Comment: oh yes, i forgot about that, thanks

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$, $g(x)=42-1/x$.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\frac1x$, and $g(x)=42-\frac1x$? Or, alternatively, let $f(x)=\sin(\frac1x)$ and $g(x)=42-\sin(\frac1x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=42-1/x$.

Comment: Why? Since $f(x)+g(x)=42$ for nonzero $x$, the limit of $f(x)+g(x)$ as $x$ tends to zero is 42.

Comment: Nvm, I misinterpreted what you were saying

Answer (score 3):

In general, any function such that $f(x)$ doesn't have a limit and $g(x) = 42 - f(x)$ would work.